# Pandas converting json to single cell csv instead of a full spreadsheet

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert JSON data in to a CSV that has headers for ID, created_at and updated_at.  In those cols should be the data provided in the JSON.  Those can change from query to query I can't just hand code them headers in.
Instead I am getting a CSV with 2 cells, Data and then cell below it with a list of everything else.

So here is the test data returned from a GraphQL API.

```
{
  "data": {
    "accounts": {
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "created_at": "2021-05-06T15:35:49+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-11-09T15:52:02+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "created_at": "2021-05-08T01:51:54+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-10-20T15:53:42+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "created_at": "2021-05-10T15:53:01+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-10-27T17:15:41+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "created_at": "2021-05-11T13:25:02+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-11-09T15:35:44+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "created_at": "2021-05-11T13:42:24+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-11-09T15:39:50+00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I an running what I thought was a pretty standard operation.

```
def json_to_csv(csv_path, json_path):
    with open(json_path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as j_input:
        df = pd.read_json(j_input)
    
    df.to_csv(csv_path, encoding='utf-8', index=False, line_terminator='\n')
```

But the output is all in one cell, the output looks like this.

```
data
"{'entities': [{'id': '1', 'created_at': '2021-05-06T15:35:49+00:00', 'updated_at': '2021-11-09T15:52:02+00:00'}, {'id': '2', 'created_at': '2021-05-08T01:51:54+00:00', 'updated_at': '2021-10-20T15:53:42+00:00'}, {'id': '3', 'created_at': '2021-05-10T15:53:01+00:00', 'updated_at': '2021-10-27T17:15:41+00:00'}, {'id': '4', 'created_at': '2021-05-11T13:25:02+00:00', 'updated_at': '2021-11-09T15:35:44+00:00'}, {'id': '5', 'created_at': '2021-05-11T13:42:24+00:00', 'updated_at': '2021-11-09T15:39:50+00:00'}]}"
```

I have not used a lot of pandas but it is supposed to the end all for data manipulation so I guessing I missed something somewhere.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you expecting the CSV to look like? Will you please add that to the question? It'll help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that iterates through the json data, stopping when it comes to a list and then making a df. If your json structure is always nested 1-entry dicts followed by a list of dicts then this will work even if the header names of the outer dicts change

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import io

j_input = io.StringIO(
"""
{
  "data": {
    "accounts": {
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "created_at": "2021-05-06T15:35:49+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-11-09T15:52:02+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "created_at": "2021-05-08T01:51:54+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-10-20T15:53:42+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "created_at": "2021-05-10T15:53:01+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-10-27T17:15:41+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "created_at": "2021-05-11T13:25:02+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-11-09T15:35:44+00:00"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "created_at": "2021-05-11T13:42:24+00:00",
          "updated_at": "2021-11-09T15:39:50+00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
"""
)


json_data = json.load(j_input)
pd_data = None

#Iterate through the json structure looking for the first list
while True:

    if type(json_data) == list:
        #If we've found a list just try to use it to make a dataframe
        pd_data = json_data
        
    if type(json_data) == dict:
        ks = list(json_data.keys())
        
        #only proceed if there is just a single dict key
        if len(ks) == 1:
            json_data = json_data[ks[0]]
            continue

    break
        

df = pd.DataFrame(pd_data)
df
```

Comment: It does sadly.  I may find a way to programmatically pull those headers though.  This gives me a rabbit hole to jump down.  Thanks!

Comment: generalized a little bit, maybe it will cover your use cases if the only change is the header names, but the structure stays mostly the same